# What pattern resembles maps of the CMB?

Tags: patterns

Maybe an odd question:

How would you describe a pattern resembling maps of the cosmic background question?

[image: cosmic background]

Say if the green/yellow/red were cast to white and the darker blues to white. I feel like “patchwork” falls short.

Comment: Fractla. Deeply fractal is the word I'd use.

Comment: You are not even showing the pattern - and you want it named! Please take a moment of your own time and make the pattern (my brain is refusing to "cast" three colours unto white and at the same time cast dark blue to what? Is the second white a typo?.) Or are you just trying to say "what pattern is the lighter blue?". So isolate what you want - and you might get (better) answers here.